# Login and register form using localstorage

Tags: html, local-storage

I am making a app using mozilla firefox webIDE. However, I encounter some difficulty with local storage storing and authenticating. Could someone advise me on that? Thanks alot.

Javascript

```
function store(theForm) {
    document.getElementById('welcomeMessage').innerHTML = "";
    var inputUsername= theForm["username"];
    var inputPassword= theForm["password"];
    localStorage.setItem("username", inputUsername.value);
    localStorage.setItem("password", inputPassword.value);
    document.getElementById('welcomeMessage').innerHTML = "Welcome " + localStorage.getItem('username') + "!";
    return false;
} 

function login(theForm) {
    document.getElementById('welcomeMessage').innerHTML = "";
    var inputUsername = theForm["username"];
    var inputPassword = theForm["password"];
    var username = inputUsername.value;
    var password = inputPassword.value;
    if ((username == localStorage.getItem('username')) && (password == localStorage.getItem('password'))) {
     document.getElementById('welcomeMessage').innerHTML = "Welcome " + localStorage.getItem('username') + "!";
      } else {
     document.getElementById('welcomeMessage').innerHTML = "Invalid Log-in!";
    }
    return false;
}
```

HTML

```
<html>
<head><title>kdkd</title></head>
<body>
<div class="popup">
<h2>Register</h2>
<p>Please enter your details here</p>
<form method="get" action="" onsubmit="return store(this);" id="register">
<label for="email">User Name</label>
<input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Select A User Name" required value="" /><br />
<label for="pass">Password</label>
<input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Select A Password" required value="" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Register" />
</form>
</div>
<br />
<div class="popup">
<h2>Welcome Guest!</h2>
<p>Please enter your login and password here</p>
<form method="get" action="" onsubmit="return login(this);" id="signon">
<label for="email">User Name </label>
<input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Your Password" required value="" /><br />
<label for="password">Password</label>
<input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Your Password" required value="" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Log In" />
</form>
<a class="close" href="#close"></a>
</div>
<script src="form.js"></script>
<body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide us the exact problem that you faced. Be specific.

Comment: It cannot work. That's the problem I am facing and I don't know why.